# Can't see the output of a function is equal to a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-files

I have a program that whenever I press a button it writes a value to a text file. The next time the button is pressed it finds the string that was written last and calls the variable to do the opposite. This continuously is running until I shut it off. My issue is it doesn't stop printing "Off", which is the last string in my text file. When the program runs, Fine() prints the last string of the text file then it goes into the while loop. It doesn't seem to recognize my if statements and just prints Fine() again without change. I don't know why it keeps printing "Off" it could be a formating thing that I don't know of, but I've looked and couldn't find anything similar to it.

```
import time
import os
# this is the system that detects the last line. In order to seek the end of file, we have to open the file in binary mode. We seek the last 2 characters
# since the file is likely to end with a newline. Then, keep reading a single byte until a newline character is found. And, finally, we use readline() to read the \
# final line, and decode() to convert from bytes to string.


# Checker is a fall back system so if there is nothing in the file then it writes on(or the terms i am using at that time.) so that when I press the button again it starts the cycle.

def Checker():
    file = open("Store.txt").readlines()
    #print(file[0:2])
    if file[0:2] != ['On\n', 'Off']:
        print("nothing is here...Restarting file with added Off")
        with open("Store.txt","w") as df:
            df.write("On\nOff")
            df.close()
    
def Fine():
    with open("Store.txt", "rb") as f:
        f.seek(-2, os.SEEK_END)
        while f.read(1) != b'\n':
            f.seek(-2, os.SEEK_CUR) 
        print(f.readline().decode())


def w_on():
    print("The light is on")
    with open("Store.txt", "w") as on:
        on.write("On\n","On")
        on.close()


def w_off():
    print("this is off")
    with open ("Store.txt", "w") as off:
        off.write("off\no","OFFF")
        off.close()
    


#This checks the status of the text file and corrects it if the text inside is wrong.
Checker()
# this prints the current last line in the Store.txt file.
Fine()


#============================================================================================
#Here is the start of my Issue of it printing "Off"

# 1==1 replaces the button.pressed() function    
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    if 1==1:
        if Fine()==("On"):
            # the print function replaces the function for the servo moving. right here the off funtion would happen.
            print("The light is turning off")
            w_off()

        elif Fine()== ("Off"):
            # the print fucntion replaces the function for the serveo moving. right below, the on funtion would happen.
            print("The light is turning on")
            w_on()


    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Can you post the entire code without replacing it? (I'm assuming that `button.pressed()` replaces `1==1` as you said in your comment). Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: So a suggestion here. Instead of calling `Fine()` two times in the `if` and `elif`, call it once and set it equal to a variable. Then check the value of that variable. Pretty sure you will find your problem then.

Comment: @12944qwerty This is my full program, I was using it for testing so when it was finished I could integrate it into my main program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is this line: `print(f.readline().decode())`

So on your first execution, you have the file written with `On` and `Off` with checker with `Off` as your last statement in the file.

Now every time you call `Fine()` in the while loop, the above statement prints the last line which is `Off` currently.

Your `Fine()` call is returning `None` (because your function doesn't return anything), therefore your `if` and `elif` don't really execute except calling `Fine()` to check its value. So nothing gets written to your file and you keep getting the last line which is still `Off`.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, knowing that I can probably figure out a way to change it so it can work. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I changed the variable the if statements are reading and I was able to fix the issue.

```
# 1==1 replaces the button.pressed() function    
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    
    with open("Store.txt", "rb") as f:
        f.seek(-2, os.SEEK_END)
        while f.read(1) != b'\n':
            f.seek(-2, os.SEEK_CUR)
        # Adeed the var Detect so I can tell the output of the reading.
        Detect = f.readline().decode()
        f.close()
        
        # Now it asks what the output of the reading is not the output of a function, so it continues through instead of returning a None.
        if Detect==("On"):
            # the print function replaces the function for the servo moving. right here the off function would happen.
            print("The light is turning off")
            w_off()

        elif Detect== ("Off"):
            # the print fucntion replaces the function for the serveo moving. right below, the on funtion would happen.
            print("The light is turning on")
            w_on()
        else:
            print("Incorrect")


    time.sleep(2)
```